# PostgreSQL referencing foreign keys over multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

Today I started to port a MySql database to PostgreSQL and I have a problem with the foreign keys and their 'sharing'

I don't know how to explain that so here is some pseudo code of the create script:

```
create table id_generator (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
description varchar(50) );

create table parent (
id REFERENCES id_generator(id),
--content );

create table child (
id REFERENCES id_generator(id),
id_parent REFERENCES parent(id),
--content );
```

So I use one table as 'id_generator' to create the id's and to give the other tables a reference to a value table. In MySql I had no problems with that so I want that to work in PostgreSQL as well.

When running that script I get the error, that I need a `primary key` / `unique` on the table `parent` to create a reference on it. so I changed it into:

```
create table id_generator (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
description varchar(50) );

create table parent (
id REFERENCES id_generator(id) PRIMARY KEY,
--content );

create table child (
id REFERENCES id_generator(id),
id_parent REFERENCES parent(id),
--content );
```

so the server accepts the create script and all is set up for some inserts.

I create the first id with:

```
insert into id_generator(description) values("parentID");
```

then I want to add a parent:

```
insert into parent(id, /*content*/) values(1, /*content*/);
```

that also works as expected, so I need to insert a `child` for `parent`:

```
insert into id_generator(description) values("childID");
insert into child(id,id_parent)values(2,1);
```

and here I get the error message "ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint DETAIL: key (id_parent)=(1) allready exists"

edit:

```
\d child;

         Tabelle ╗public.child½
      Spalte       |   Typ   | Attribute
-------------------+---------+-----------
      id           | integer | not null
      id_parent    | integer |
Indexe:
    "child_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)Fremdschlⁿssel-Constraints:
    "child_id_parent_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id_parent) REFERENCES parent(id)
    "child_id_generator_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES id_generator(id)
```

how can I solve that?

Comment: Show the child table structure with `=> \d child` and a `select * from child`

Comment: done; `child` is empty

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am sorry, problem solved, had a double call of the insert statement :facepalm: